# Creating Dummy Sets in MATLAB for statistics

Tags: matlab, correlation, categorical-data

i am looking at creating dummy sets in MATLAB, first i created an array of random variable with 10 instances of min=5 and max =10, and here is my code `r = (10-5).*rand(10,1) + 5;` Please I need help on how to create the following;

1: create additional variable that is dependent on my first variable (r) with positive correlation?

2: create additional variable that is dependent on my first variable (r) with negative correlation?

3: create a sphare shaped data set?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably didn't receive any attention because you didn't tag your post with the MATLAB tag.  I would have seen your post if you did!  I added the tag in, as well as provided you with an answer.  Next time when you make a question, it is very important you tag which programming languages you're using for better exposure, and for quicker response.

Comment: Noted, Many thanks! Well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple to do.  In terms of two-dimensional problems, data that exhibit a positive correlation are those data points where there is clearly an increase in the output for every increase in the independent value `r`.  Similarly, for negative correlation, there is a decrease in the output for every increase in the independent value `r`.

Therefore, what you can do is simply define an equation of the line of the type `y = mx + b` where `m` and `b` are determined *a priori*.  Once you have these terms, you simply add whatever noise you want on top of this line to generate your "correlated" noise.  Therefore, given `m` and `b`, you would solve the first two questions like so:

## Question #1

Define a **positive** slope for `m`... something like `m = 2`.

```
rng(123); %// For reproducibility
m = 2; %// Set positive slope
b = 4;
r = (10-5).*rand(10,1) + 5; %// Produce 10 random points
x = (1 : 10).'; %// Define x values from 1 - 10
y = m*x + b + r; %// Generate output and plot
plot(x, y, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 16);
```

We get:

[image]

## Question #2

Define a **negative** slope for `m`... something like `m = -2`.

```
rng(123); %// For reproducibility
m = -2; %// Set positive slope
b = 4;
r = (10-5).*rand(10,1) + 5; %// Produce 10 random points
x = (1 : 10).'; %// Define x values from 1 - 10
y = m*x + b + r; %// Generate output and plot
plot(x, y, 'b.');
```

We get:

[image]

## Question #3

This actually will be a bit more complicated.  What you should do is given a centre and a radius, you simply generate a bunch of 2D coordinates that are within the circle, then randomly then check to see whether or not the equation of the circle is satisfied:

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 <= r^2
```

If it is, then we keep the point.  It'll be easier to centre the random point generation at around `-1 <= (x,y) <= 1`, then we check to see if the radius is less than 1 to satisfy our check.  Once we find those points, we will scale the points by the radius, then move the centre over.  Bear in mind that `rand` only produces values between `[0,1]`.  As such, to generate values between `[-1,1]`, we multiply by 2 and subtract by 1.

Something like:

```
rng(123);
pts = 2*rand(1000,2) - 1; %// Generate points between [-1,1]
dists = sum(pts.^2, 2); %// Find distances from the centre
pts(dists > 1, :) = []; %// Any values beyond radius of 1 filter
centre = [2 2]; %// Set centre and radius
radius = 5;
pts = radius*pts; %// Scale points by radius
pts = bsxfun(@plus, pts, centre); %// Move points over
plot(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 16); %// Plot points and adjust viewing axis
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
```

We get:

[image]